# Passing a list of custom types to a GraphQL mutation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, graphql, apollo

The goal of my app is for a user to be able to save and recall a list of forms to be filled out and edited. One user will have many forms, and a single form will be made up of several fields of its own.

If my have my types set up like this, for example:

```
const FormType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'FormType',
  fields: {
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    email: { type: GraphQLString }
  }
});
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'UserType',
  fields: {
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    email: { type: GraphQLString },
    firstName: { type: GraphQLString, default: '' },
    lastName: { type: GraphQLString, default: '' },
    phone: { type: GraphQLString, default: '' },
    forms: { type: new GraphQLList(FormType) }
  }
});
```

And my mutation like this:

```
const mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Mutation',
  fields: {
    saveForm: {
      type: UserType,
      args: {
        userID: { type: GraphQLID },
        form: { type: FormType } // ???
      },
      resolve(parentValue, { userID, form }) {
        // I'll figure out what to do here when the time comes
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I can't seem to create a mutation that works with `GraphQLList`. I keep getting this error:

> Error: Mutation.saveForm(form:) argument type must be Input Type but
>   got: FormType.

...which my research is telling me means that `FormType` needs to be a `GraphQLInputObjectType`. When I change it accordingly, I just get the error:

> Error: Mutation.saveForm(form:) argument type must be Output Type but
>   got: FormType.

So nothing really changes. Does anyone know of a working example of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is because while you've correctly changed your input type to be a `GraphQLInputObjectType`, that changes the type of field `UserType.forms` to an input type too - remember `UserType` is an output type. Here you would need to make a `FormType` and also a `FormInputType`, and use each in the appropriate place.

Separately: why do you need a full input type for a form? Wouldn't it function equally well to just pass in the ID? Or, if the intention is to have `FormType` represent form data, why does it need an ID? Also, perhaps it could be named better to `FormData`?

Finally, while I believe this provides an answer, your question didn't provide completely cut+pasteable code for a minimal, complete and verifiable example so that I could easily check.

Comment: So instead of trying to pass in a list of FormTypes objects, I should just pass in a list of their IDs? That makes a lot of sense, that wouldn't upset the GraphQLList either I assume.

The thinking originally about the input type for a form is because the form itself is very complex, and I would like to create it from several smaller types, similarly to how my React components are structured. I figured once I know how to pass the Form type to the user, then I could apply the same logic to the form sub-types.

Comment: I think I'm missing something here. Wouldn't I need a separate mutation to save the form (thereby generating the `ID`) before I can pass it to the `User`?

I know I'm probably missing something, but I've been making no progress on this for a couple of days now and it's starting to drive me up the wall. I apologize if anything I say at this point seems obvious. Anything I can further clarify to make this easier to understand I will provide.

Comment: No reason to apologise! This is still quite cutting-edge stuff. Am I right that the original title, "passing a list of custom types", isn't quite right? And that actually you need to pass in a set (or in GraphQL terms, object) of form data? It appears to me that "form" is not really the essential thing here, but perhaps a list of questions?

Comment: Also, please check and let us all know whether the last sentence in my first paragraph is right: that you could achieve what you want with parallel "types" of `GraphQLObjectType` and `GraphQLInputObjectType`?

Comment: It turns out my issue might be more related to how I'm trying to structure my data. Basically, I'm trying to figure out how I can create a mutation that will save a form to the database, but the form is made of a few nested schemas that I was planning to treat as "types" in my query, hence the original question. Is it bad practice, or even possible to do this?

Comment: I realize I would probably have to use some kind of system of nested mutations to accomplish this, but figuring out how to pull that off is proving difficult.

Comment: I don't think you'd need nested mutations, but you might need a sequence of mutations to build up your desired inputs. Conceivably you might also benefit from using https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-type-json as a sort of escape-hatch with arbitrary JSON.

Comment: Just thought I'd come back to let you know that it was InputObjectTypes I needed all along. :) I just didn't fully understand how to implement them from your comment, but it set me on the right track in the end. Needless to say, I know a LOT more about GraphQL and Mongoose now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer helped you, you might accept it?